# Blasting the side of a platform gives you 150 points as if you were blasting a troll

Tags: bug, status-completed, april-fools, unikong

First, great game!  You can blast trolls with your ray gun for 150 reputation each!  But you can also blast the side of the platform in Level 3 for 150 points too!  That's how Jon Skeet gets so much reputation -- he just touches his keyboard and reputation instantly appears.

Here, in level 3, I have 6,120 reputation.  The board is cleared of badges, diamonds, and trolls, and I'm about to shoot the platform to the upper left by jumping and firing.

[image: Before - 6,120 points]

I've hit the side of the platform 2 times and I'm about to hit it again here.  My reputation has gone up 300 points to 6,420 points.

[image: After - 6,420 points]

I'm guessing that the code to register a hit on a troll doesn't check what it hits - troll or side of platform.

Here's my score 30 seconds later:

[image: Well after = 20,970 points!]

You can fire will standing on the ladder, so this is the inevitable result:

[image: Just before 1M rep!]

1,000,020 reputation!

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now that this is fixed, I retire as the Unikong King!

[image]

Comment: The platform is an enemy!

Comment: 1,000,020 reputation? Suspended for having more rep than Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Congratulations! You found the secret *feature*!**

...Yeah, I'll get on fixing that now.

**EDIT:** fixed and live in a few minutes. Thanks for reporting and detailing with screenshots! :)

Comment: Ugh. Early access is the worst. Tell me when this game is _finished_.

Comment: We're offering full refunds for dissatisfied players.

Comment: Feature request: convert Unikong rep into actual rep on the site. :P

Comment: @Haney it's almost as though adding new features an hour before it goes live was a bad idea or something?

Comment: @MarcGravell the bane of all programmers... procrastination.

Comment: Also noticed that you can jump on coins. Cool feature.. similar to Mario's run and wall jump

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: reloaded the page and it's fixed. Thanks @Haney!

This is still happening:

[image]

Comment: You probably need a hard reload and/or to clear cache. Try shift-reloading and let me know. Guaranteed it's fixed! :)

Comment: @Haney OK, refresh worked. Sorry about that!

Comment: No need to apologize at all! Glad it's good to go. :)