# Trolls Can Be Shot Twice

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unikong

When playing the Unikong game, I found another gun-based bug similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277734/blasting-the-side-of-a-platform-gives-you-150-points-as-if-you-were-blasting-a-t). If you fire two shots at a troll in rapid succession, each shot will trigger 150 points. I believe the intended behavior is for each troll to be plugged once.

Granted, it's not enough to get you over a million rep, but as anyone who's ever worked at their respective "Exchange" account, every bit helps.

Comment: Shooting them twice makes sure they're dead. No harm in wasting three laser rounds of ammo if you get four times the score.

Comment: @AdamLear I guess a slightly more accurate tag would be [tag:status-dontcare]

Comment: You can't change the question to something else like that. You reported this as a bug, got official reply as a bug. You can't all of a sudden change this into something else. This is valid bug report, that happen to be the intended behavior, that's it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the downvotes, I appreciate the welcoming committee.

Comment: @Dykotomee Well, [voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).  In this case it means people disagree this is a bug, I guess?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to understand that @Joe. I thought my question was well-worded, well-researched (I looked at other posts, etc.), but I guess the "perceived usefulness" is a factor too.

Also, I suppose I should not be commenting on responses with 3 hours of sleep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm okay with rewarding the effort to make sure the trolls are well and truly dead with a bit of extra rep.

[Service guarantees citizenship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_7FaWnlhS4).

Answer (score 4):

It's actually possible to shoot those pesky trolls *more than twice*, if you fire while moving down a ladder and manage to catch their falling carcass with a well timed series of extra shots.  Example:

**Before:** (score = 4350)
[image: Before]

**After:** (score = 5100)
[image: After]

Difference: minus one troll, plus 750 = 5 × 150 points. :)

Comment: Where did you play? Or are those old screenshots? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: https://unikong.github.io/